# Passing parameters in a variable Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to disable "`Email Apps`" features on `Azure admin center` for an off-boarding script. I'm not sure if I can pass a few parameters into a `foreach` loop, below is the code. I've ran the code with param defined and without param defined.

```
param(
  [parameter]$DisableApps
)
$DisableApps = ("OWAEnabled" , "EwsEnabled" , "PopEnabled")
foreach ($i in $DisableApps){Set-CASMailbox "Sahand.Test" $i $false}
```

**The error I am getting is -**

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
>   '-OWAEnabled'.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-CASMailbox], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Set-CASMailbox
>       + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com

Comment: [According to the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/client-access/set-casmailbox?view=exchange-ps), `Set-CASMailbox` has an enormous amount of parameters.  Make sure you're naming them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think you may be looking for is called [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675931.aspx)

If you define your parameters in a hashtable, you can pass them as parameters when you use `@` as a splat operator. (Note that `@` has other uses besides being the splat operator.)

```
param(
    [string]$Identity = "Sahand.Test",
    [switch]$DisableApps 
)
If ($DisableApps) {
    $CASMailboxParams = @{
        Identity =  $Identity
        OWAEnabled = $False
        EwsEnabled = $False
        PopEnabled = $False
    }
    Set-CASMailbox @CASMailboxParams
} else {
    Set-CASMailbox $Identity
}
```

Then by using your script parameters, you can use `-DisableApps` to set the those parameters to false.

```
.\examplescript.ps1 -Identity 'differentuser' -DisableApps
```

Comment: Not sure `@` is a "splat operator" considering its use in the array and hashtable syntaxes.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 From the linked [TechNet article on Splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675931.aspx): _The “@” sign, when used as a splat operator, does something similar._ Answer updated for clarity

Comment: Thank you for your help, I ended up modifying your code. I have read splatting once before when I was trying to invoke commands and had to define parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
param([bool]$CASMailboxParams, [string]$User)
$User = "Sahand.Test"
$CASMailboxParams = @{
    OWAEnabled = $False
    EwsEnabled = $False
    PopEnabled = $False
}
        Set-CASMailbox -Identity $User @CASMailboxParams
        Get-CASMailbox $User
```

This will allow you to pass parameters through a command and check it the casmailbox at the end. Note:This script is for Exchange Powershell.